# Using Kannel with and SMSC simulator for sending and receiving SMS

Tags: smpp, kannel

I am working on a project Using Kannel in order to send/receive SMS, So far we were told to read the documentation about Kannel and also do a simulation. I was able to use Opensmpp to send SMS but i am having troubles in receiving SMS to my Kannel in order to process it. if there is any chance of doing that with OpenSmpp please tell me, cuz i am stuck here. if not could you refer me to another SMSC simulator that could give me that possibility.
Thanks You in Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can highly suggest using SMPPSIM from Selenium Software as a SMSC simulator. Last time I got it from [here](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/downloads.html). It needs Java, but if I remember correctly so did OpenSMPP. Once you have it up and running you can connect to it's Web Interface port that allows you to inject messages that will be sent to the connected clients. It also allows for ESME-to-ESME mode that basically sends back everything you send it.

Comment: Could you please show a code sample how to run OpenSMPP in transceiver mode. I can successfully send messages to SMSC but cannot get delivery response.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for your answer. I used SMPPSIm and it worked well. I am gonna put my configuration hopefully this will help someone.
Kannel.conf :

```
#kannel.conf
group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 14000
admin-password = saad
log-file = /home/saad/klogs/kannel.log
log-level = 0
access-log = /home/saad/klogs/access_kannel.log
dlr-storage = pgsql

#--- postgresql connection
group = pgsql-connection
id = mydlr
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 5432
username = saad
password = ****
database = kannelDb
max-connections = 1

#---- DLR table structure
group = dlr-db
id = mydlr
table = "kannel_dlr"
field-smsc = smsc
field-timestamp = timstamp
field-destination = destination
field-source = source
field-service = service
field-url = url
field-mask = mask
field-status = status
field-boxc-id = boxc_id

group = smsbox
#smsbox-id = mysmsbox  do not uncomment this if you have only one smsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
sendsms-port = 1025
#global-sender = 1000
log-file = /home/saad/klogs/smsbox.log
log-level = 0
mo-recode = true

group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = SMPPSim
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 2775
transceiver-mode = 1
receive-port = 2775
smsc-username = smppclient1
smsc-password = password
system-type = 'VMA'
#service-type = 'test'
interface-version = 34
#system-id = smppclient
preferred-smsc-id = SMPPSim

group = sendsms-user
username = saad
password = ****
#forced-smsc = SMPPSim
default-sender = '1000'


group = sms-service
keyword = default
accept-x-kannel-headers = true
#text = "No service specified"
catch-all = true
max-messages = 0 # it's better to put this parameter to 0 or you will have a lot Ack in      your network
get-url = "http://localhost/kannel/?phone=%p&text=%a"
```

Comment: hello, does kanel forward to the url you specified to process inbound sms

Comment: Hi @Smith, yes it does, all you have to do is put the appropriate url on get-url parameter and it will forward to that url everytime Kannel receives an SMS.

Comment: ok, one more question how do i send  sms from my php application to a virtual number or to kanel, so that when it receives it will then forward to my url

Comment: Hi Smith, u can use the virtual smsc SMPPSIM [link](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/user-guide.htm) to send/recevie sms and test your code.

Comment: Did you try this in a `Linux` environment or `Windows`?

Comment: Hi, I was doing the project on a `Linux` environment